# A Computation in Polar Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $B_t$ be a ball of radius t. There's a function $u$ that's defined everywhere. I'm reading a calculation that makes the following equality:
$$\int_o^t\int_{\partial B_r}\chi_{\left\{u\left(t \frac{x}{\lvert x \rvert} \right)> 0 \right\}} \, d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(x)\,dr = \frac t n \int_{\partial B_t}\chi_{\left\{u> 0 \right\}} \, d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$$
I don't exactly follow the computation, I thought $\frac t n$ should be $\frac{t^{n}}n$ but I read this equality elsewhere in the paper so I don't think its a typo. Perhaps its the change of variables $x \rightarrow \frac x t$ but I'm having trouble getting this to work because this conversion is cartesian, not polar.

Comment: I edited the fraction, thanks! Can you be a bit more explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform $x\in\partial B_r\mapsto \frac{t}rx=t\frac{x}{\lvert x\vert}\in\partial B_t$.  So $$\int_{\partial B_r}f\left(t\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(x)=\int_{\partial B_t}f(y)\,\left(\frac{r}t\right)^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(y)$$
and hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^t\int_{\partial B_r}f\left(t\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(x)
&=\int_0^t\int_{\partial B_t}f(y)\,\left(\frac{r}t\right)^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(y)\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&=\int_{\partial B_t} f(y)\,\mathrm{d}\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(y)
\underbrace{\int_0^t\left(\frac{r}t\right)^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}r}_{t/n}.
\end{aligned}
$$